# How to obtain sharp edged view in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, canvas

is it possible to obtain below view in react native either using *canvas* or *View*?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure it's achievable if you use

1. Grey layer - White background with grey foreground, with borderBottomLeftRadius
2. White Layer - borderBottomLeftRadius BorderTopRightRadius
3. another layer with borderTopRightRadius

Example for grey layer

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFF', height: 20 }}>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", borderBottomLeftRadius: '20%'}}>
        content
    </View>
</View>
```

You just have to play around with the background colors, borderColor and borderradius etc. Though it may not look exactly the same as what you want. and may appear different on different devices

Comment: but is it possible to obtain sharp edges on bottomright? It would be of great help if there was a way to obtain sharp edge

Comment: u need to create one more view at the bottom, a 3rd view. You may not be ablel to achieve the shadow effect though

Comment: Yea got it, I will try it out